# Australia vs New Zeland underarm ball

Tags: rules, cricket

Is this still legal in cricket? And since it was legal, why would people get so upset?

[Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2qpj-yBkwY)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [law 24 in ICC's Match Playing Conditions <sup>PDF</sup>](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/524ac43be2aca-Standard%20Test%20Match.pdf): (emphasis mine)

> #### 24.1 - Mode of delivery
>
> Law 24.1 (b) shall be replaced by the following:
>
> The bowler may not deliver the ball underarm. **If a bowler bowls a ball underarm the umpire shall call and signal no ball**, and the ball is to be re-bowled overarm.

So bowling a ball underarm is not legal. It is considered a *no ball* unless special agreement before the match <sup>1</sup>.

However, at that time bowling an underarm ball was legal but it was against the spirit of cricket. And it was deliberately bowled just to prevent New Zealand hitting a six on the last ball. That's why whole cricketing world was upset for that decision. For more see [a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underarm_bowling_incident_of_1981) regarding that incident.

---

<sup>1. As per [law 24.1(b) in lords.org](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-24-no-ball/). However, this is not specified in ICC's match playing conditions.</sup>

Comment: Why is it against the spirit of cricket?  I guess I don't see a difference between that and running out the clock in another sport.  If there is no chance of hitting a six then they will win...